# How to find difference between two rows with conditions

Tags: oracle

```
name      point
----------
steve     207
Mary      203
steve     205
steve     200
steve     139
Mary      300
```

I want to get the difference between the rows with condition eqn = [ (row + 1) - row] where name = steve, so I would ideally want it to be,

```
steve 2   //207 - 0
steve 5   //205 - 207
steve 61  //200 - 205
steve 139 //139 - 200
```

there are codes available to find the difference between consecutive rows. but it will not work when condition is added.

Comment: How do you determine which row is `row` and which row is `row + 1`? There is no intrinsic order to the way rows are returned from the database without an explicit order being imposed by the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edited due OP comment** I have changed query to match exactly your request.

[LAG](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php) can helps you:

```
  select name, 
    coalesce( 
        point - lag( point , 1, Null ) over (order by point),
        point)
    as diff,
    point || '-' ||
    LEAD( point , 1, 0 ) over (order by point) as prev_point
  from t   
  where name = 'steve'  
  order by point desc
```

[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6fb32/19/0):

```
|  NAME | DIFF | PREV_POINT |
-----------------------------
| steve |    2 |      207-0 |
| steve |    5 |    205-207 |
| steve |   61 |    200-205 |
| steve |  139 |    139-200 |
```

Comment: This provides it in a random order though. The OP doesn't seem to want that.

Comment: @Ben, you are right. Be free to [fork sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6fb32/6/0) when OP answer your comment. Regards!

Comment: is it possible to add condition 'is not null' for the points? means if prev_point is 0, then it will not be display.

Comment: |  NAME | POINT | PREV_POINT | DIFF |
-------------------------------------
| steve |   205 |        207 |    2 |
| steve |   200 |        205 |    5 |
| steve |   139 |        200 |   61 |

Comment: @user1816507, I have updated answer to match your answer query. Please, change answer (or better put a new one) with new requeriments. Glad to help. Alert me with news.

Comment: @danihp, I tried your code at SQL Fiddle and it works there. but it does not work when i implement it into my code. it still display as the previous result. i run my code in oracle

Comment: post a new question with your oracle version and code environment. somethink like: This query don't run for me in oracle XX with php ... error code is ... or results are wrong ...